# Unable to modify a dataset before binding to gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

I need to modify a dataset before binding it to a gridview.
When I walk through the complete code block, and hover over dsEmployeeOrg, that records 
dont appear modified.  What am I missing here?

My code is:

```
                DataSet dsEmployeeOrg = eCorporateStaffMgr.GetEmployeeAccessLevel(oEmp);
                DataTable dt = dsEmployeeOrg[0];

                string sManagerID = "";
                string sSupervisorID = "";
                string sEmployeeID = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < dsEmployeeOrg.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    sManagerID = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString().Trim();
                    sSupervisorID = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString().Trim();
                    sEmployeeID = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString().Trim();

                    if ((sManagerID.ToString().Trim() != sSupervisorID.ToString().Trim()) && (sManagerID.ToString().Trim() != sEmployeeID.ToString().Trim()))
                    {
                        if (sSupervisorID.ToString().Trim() == sEmployeeID.ToString().Trim())
                        {
                            // This is a Supervisor record
                            dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2] = "1111";
                        }
                        else if (sSupervisorID.ToString().Trim() != sEmployeeID.ToString().Trim())
                        {
                            //This is a Employee record
                            dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2] = "0000";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Did you call the dt.AcceptChanges() somewhere? Just curious, why you are still doing things with DataSet?

Comment: dt.AcceptChanges() did  not fix the issue.

Comment: You can use Entity Framework or at least Microsoft Enterprose Library to build you data access layer. So the issue is you are not getting the modified data into the GridView?

Comment: correct... the data is not getting modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your code as below

```
DataSet dsEmployeeOrg = eCorporateStaffMgr.GetEmployeeAccessLevel(oEmp);
DataTable dt = dsEmployeeOrg[0];
string sManagerID = "";
string sSupervisorID = "";
string sEmployeeID = "";

for (int i = 0; i < dsEmployeeOrg.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
   sManagerID = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString().Trim();
   sSupervisorID = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString().Trim();
   sEmployeeID = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString().Trim();

   if ((sManagerID.ToString().Trim() != sSupervisorID.ToString().Trim()) && (sManagerID.ToString().Trim() != sEmployeeID.ToString().Trim()))
   {
       if (sSupervisorID.ToString().Trim() == sEmployeeID.ToString().Trim())
       {
          // This is a Supervisor record
          dt.Rows[i][2] = "1111";
       }
       else if (sSupervisorID.ToString().Trim() != sEmployeeID.ToString().Trim())
       {
          //This is a Employee record
          dt.Rows[i][2] = "0000";
       }
   }
}
```